# nativeElement.value is NaN if there is a comma

Tags: javascript, angular, nan

I'm trying to set the number of decimals at 2 in an input. When I type a comma in it, the value becomes NaN so I would like get my number instead of this.

TS

```
 @ViewChild('number') input;

     limitNbOfDecimals() {
    var regex =
      this.form.number.search(/^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{0,2})?)$/) == 0
        ? true
        : false;

    if (regex == false) { 
      // Convert the value to a number
      var nb: number = +this.input.nativeElement.value;  
      //set decimals at 2
      this.input.nativeElement.value = nb.toFixed(2);
      
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="form.number"
                  #number
                  name="number"
                  (input)="limitNbOfDecimals()"
                />
```

EDIT

I manage to add a comma in the number but if I try to add more than 2 decimals after it removes the numbers after the comma like 1,11 -> 1

Comment: Comma is not valid for number. Replace `,` to `.` in your value and parse it as float. `parseFloat(this.input.nativeElement.value.replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: I think some (maybe only Firefox??) will support a localised format for number type if region is set so you could use comma, but I don't think it's supported e.g. on Chrome. There is discussion of this e.g. https://www.ryadel.com/en/html-input-type-number-with-localized-decimal-values-jquery/ so either you have to warn your users to use the decimal point . or use a text type input and parse the whole thing yourself.

Comment: It's not `value` that is `NaN`, it's your `+ value` cast that doesn't work on strings containing a comma

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, in the sense of having a total solution, but hopefully helps you get to one (and it's too long for a comment).

The spec at [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)](http://Just%20found%20this%20in%20the%20spec%20at%20https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)) states:

> This specification does not define what user interface user agents
> are to use; user agent vendors are encouraged to consider what would
> best serve their users' needs. ..... a user agent designed for the
> French market might display the value with apostrophes between
> thousands and commas before the decimals, and allow the user to enter
> a value in that manner, internally converting it to the submission
> format described above.

It would seem that the only sure way - if you don't have control over what browsers your users have - of ensuring they can type numbers in the format they are used to in their local setting is to take input as type text and on each keystroke check that they have typed something valid (as you have defined it) and when they submit it convert to a decimal number.

Searching provides code for doing this, depending on exactly what your requirement is for the number formats though you may be better off coding it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

To add more than 2 decimal values, you need to tell like .toFixed(4) etc..

Comment: I have to set 2 decimals max so I can't change this.